# Calculating the amount of text it will take to fill a given container

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, measure

I am trying to develop a Greek Bible app and want to draw the attributed strings in pages using a UIView which will be swiped left or right like a book.  The problem is I cannot for the life of me figure out how much text it will take to fill up each page before I draw it.  I need to figure out where to start the text on the next or prev pages so no text is lost.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I have scoured the internet for clues but to no avail.

Comment: SO is not a 'homework' service(note homework is in quotes) what have you tried so far? What specific coding question do you have?

Comment: I can draw the pages and swipe them left and right.  I need to know how much text to draw on each page so no text gets lost.  In other words, how do I measure the amount of text it will take to fill up the page so that I can keep drawing the rest of the text on the following pages without losing any text.  Also, I am not sure what you mean by a 'homework' service.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you're planning on sending to the App Store - apple will reject you and ask that you instead build an iBook.  Just to save you some trouble down the road. To pass as an app you need to use a hardware feature like the camera or gps, etc..etc.

As for figuring out the amount of text to show, it's probably easiest to manually figure it out and set a max character value. 

You can scroll, and truncate, but there's no other way than visual to determine if you want text to go to the next page.

Comment: Thanks.  The app will be more than just a book.  It has a built-in dictionary and quizzing apparatus for studying and memorizing the Greek text of the New Testament.  I appreciate your response.